# I need advice to settings Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have to install two nginx in one VM. First one use 80 port and the other use other port(8080).

nginx#1(80 port) work successfully. But nginx#2(8080 port) cannot proxy to other server.

---

This is current settings.

[image]

Scenario #1 : http://10.10.10.10 -> http://10.10.10.10/app1(http://10.10.10.20:7010/app1)  :: success

Scenario #2 : http://10.10.10.10/app -> http://10.10.10.10/app1(http://10.10.10.20:7010/app1)  :: succes

Scenario #3 : http://10.10.10.10:8080 -> http://10.10.10.10/app1/app2  :: fail

---

What is the problem in Scenario#3? I want to move to http://10.10.10.10:8080(http://10.10.10.30:7010/app2).

Comment: One obvious difference is the use of proxy_path and proxy_pass. You should share your actual configuration as text, not images and share what happens beyond 'it fails'.